# Will MySQL ALTER TABLE reformat field data?

Tags: mysql, sql, types

I need to alter a table to change the Type of a column. If the current column Type is DECIMAL(8,2) and I alter that column to be DOUBLE, will the already-existing data in the column also be changed to reflect the column's new Type?

Comment: Create a test table with some data with DECIMAL(8,2). Then do the alter table. After this test tell us what happened!

Comment: I think it does but you could just create a database and give it a go with some test data. Cheers

Comment: @OMG Ponies -- Thanks for the edit, much better now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should.  However, always be safe when altering existing tables.

My preferred way of doing this type of operation is:

1. make a backup
2. create a new column
3. update all rows moving the old data over to new column
4. inspect the new column for anything wrong and fix if necessary
5. delete the old column